Lambda Provisioned Concurrency showing 0 available. But I'm not using any
I have been using my AWS account for more than 4 months. Now, I need to create a Lambda function with provisioned concurrency. However, it gives the following error:
```The maximum allowed provisioned concurrency is 0, based on the unreserved concurrency available (10) minus the minimum unreserved account concurrency (10)``

How can I resolve this issue?
I need help fixing this issue.

Maybe other Lambdas in your account are configured with reserved concurrency so that's nothing left for the new Lambda?

The default limit for lambda concurrency is 1000 per account-region across all lambdas. There can possibly be 2 reasons why this is happening:

You have other lambda functions in the account that is using the concurrency
Your account is new (which is not your case as it is 4 month old) or your account is not having much usage, and aws has set lower limits for both cases.

In either of the 2 scenarios, go to "Quota" service of AWS from your aws account service tab and raise a limit increase request, once the request is served, you can make the changes.
